# maintain state between custom tag calls?

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to maintain state between tag calls?  I need to store the last item passed to a tag that I have created.  It appeared as if I could use context to do this, but it doesn't seem to work.  Here is my code:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def date_divider(context, date):
    if 'last_date' not in context or context['last_date'] != date:
        # display new date header
        context['last_date'] = date
    return date_header
```

The problem is that a new date header is always created even if the date passed in should match the date in the context.

I'm guessing I'm using context wrong here...  Is there a way to store this last date in the context or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely that the context into which you are entering `last_date` no longer exists the second time you reach this tag (for instance, perhaps that context has been popped already?).  A (sort of hackish) solution is to be sure that you insert `last_date` into the "highest" context:

```
if 'last_date' not in context.dicts[0] or context.dicts[0]['last_date'] != date:
    context.dicts[0]['last_date'] = date
```

This kind of approach is often needed when the tags that you are writing aren't "nested", I've found.  Incidentally, I've also found that tags of this sort are themselves often a hack!

(Not to say this particular case is, just that *my* cases have been).